# Clear multiple lines from stdout

Tags: node.js, console, stdout

I am trying to write multiple lines to the console in Node.JS then clear all of the lines I wrote.

```
process.stdout.write(['a', 'b', 'c'].join('\n'))

setInterval(() => {
    process.stdout.clearLine(0);
    process.stdout.write(['d', 'e', 'f'].join('\n'));
}, 1000)
```

I've seen some solutions that clear the whole console, I do not want this. I just want to clear what I've written to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of there is better way to do this, but what I do is move the cursor up 1 line at the time and than clear that line.

```js
const clearLines = (n) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      //first clear the current line, then clear the previous line
      const y = i === 0 ? null : -1
      process.stdout.moveCursor(0, y)
      process.stdout.clearLine(1)
    }
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0)
  }
```